# Move spam emails from directory - bash script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I am trying to write bash script wich can cleanup my whoole server from spam emails that already are present in my client's folders. I would need this script to do,

Check recursively directory /var/qmail/mailnames/* for array of keywords if files with keyword has been found go two levels up to and move files there.

I have started to write something like this, but it will not work as i need. First thing is that i get Argument list too log.

```
grep -lir 'discount' /var/qmail/mailanmes/* | xargs mv -t /var/qmail/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your globbing pattern. `/var/qmail/mailanmes/*` expands to too long a command line. What you should do is:

```
find /var/qmail/mailnames -regex '.*discount.*' -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t /var/qmail
```